# Spark SQL: Specify column name resulting from UDF in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have written a UDF function which will return a column (0 or 1) after processing 2 columns. I need to have my select query such that it returns those records for which this value is 1.
I wrote the query as below:

```
SELECT number, myUDF(col1, col2) as result
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE result is not null
```

However it doesn't recognize the column name 'result'. Is there any special syntax needed so that it recognizes this new output column? Thanks.

Comment: This is what I found. `The WHERE clause is processed before the SELECT clause(*), and so the aliases aren't available. Move to using a subquery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CASE statement should solve the problem here:

`SELECT number, 
CASE when myUDF(col1, col2) = 1 then myUDF(col1, col2) END as result
FROM mytable`

Comment: Great. Thanks. But will this be optimal? Will the UDF be called twice or it will be optimized?